# Property 'headers' is missing in type when initial near api connection

Tags: nearprotocol

I got this error when init contract in my React project. It showed when i using .tsx file. After checked the documentation from near-api-js and it didn't explain what is the headers, but when i go inside the package it actually have the 'headers' inside near.d.ts.

```js
  

const nearConfig = getConfig(process.env.NEAR_ENV || 'testnet');
const keyStore = new nearAPI.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore();
const near = await nearAPI.connect({ keyStore, ...nearConfig });
```

[image]

Comment: How does your `getConfig()` function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are missing one property in your `nearConfig` object, which is `headers`. The property can be an empty object (`{}`.)

I think you can add `headers:{}` when you connect to the nearAPI, like this:

```ts
const near = await nearAPI.connect({ keyStore, headers: {}, ...nearConfig });
```

Or, you can add `headers` in your `getConfig()` function.

The reason you need to add it is because the `TypeScript` definition of `ConnectConfig` requires it to be present.

From the [type definition in near-api-js](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/lib/near.d.ts#L55):

```ts
/**
 * NEAR RPC API headers. Can be used to pass API KEY and other parameters.
 * @see {@link JsonRpcProvider.JsonRpcProvider | JsonRpcProvider}
 */
headers: {
    [key: string]: string | number;
};
```

Comment: Yes adding headers: {} solved the error, just wondering why nearAPI does not have definition and explanation for the headers props.

Comment: Maybe it's not written directly in in the documentation, but the comment in the source code says it's used for NEAR RPC API headers. I think you can use this attribute to add headers (think HTTP Headers,) for example to pass an API-Key: `headers: {"X-API-Key": "myApiKey"}`